# .Net MVC App is constantly compiling - how do I find out why?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, health-monitoring

I am using health monitoring on a site and it seems to recompile every minute or so or even more often.  I do not always lose session state though.

Here is my Health Monitoring code from my web.config

```
    <healthMonitoring enabled="true">
        <eventMappings>
            <clear/>
            <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent, System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647"/>
    <add name="Application Events" type="System.Web.Management.WebApplicationLifetimeEvent" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647"/>
        </eventMappings>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="EmailErrorProvider" type="System.Web.Management.SimpleMailWebEventProvider" to="me@mydomain.com" from="me@mydomain.com" buffer="false" subjectPrefix="Error: " bodyHeader="This email is generated from my application."/>
    <add name="EmailErrorProvider2" type="System.Web.Management.SimpleMailWebEventProvider" to="me@mydomain.com" from="me@mydomain.com" buffer="false" subjectPrefix="App Start / App End: " bodyHeader="This email is generated from my application."/>
        </providers>
        <rules>
            <clear/>
            <add name="Testing Mail Event Providers" eventName="All Errors" provider="EmailErrorProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" custom=""/>
    <add name="Application Events Default" eventName="Application Events" provider="EmailErrorProvider2" profile="Default" minInstances="1"             maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00" />
        </rules>
    </healthMonitoring>
```

Here is a notification:

```
    ** Events **
---------------
Event code: 1003
Event message: Application compilation is starting.
Event time: 11/3/2009 6:46:54 PM
Event time (UTC): 11/3/2009 11:46:54 PM
Event ID: dd8d7deee3c048b1bef67b77aa6849bc Event sequence: 3 Event occurrence: 2 Event detail code: 0

Process information:
    Process ID: 6632
    Process name: devenv.exe
    Account name: Max-Acer\Max

---------------
```

Comment: Is the timestamp of your files and the computer date correct? Check that you don't have files with a "future" timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that it's compiling views. Try [pre-compiling your views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc) and see if you still have the same problems.

Comment: That makes sense and I just read a blog post about compiling .aspx pages and just came back here to add that to this post -  http://tinyurl.com/wf6p6