# ASP.Net MVC - Compiler Errors in Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I wonder if anyone can explain why Visual Studio does not report compile errors on the View Pages?

I ask because I noticed that Re-Sharper (At least i think it is) picks up the fact that I have included a dead referance in my view but the project will build.

eg,

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Site.This.Is.Dead.Link"%>
```

Its only when navigating to the page that this error is displayed. I think with MVC, as there is some logic and referances in the View, it would be a good thing for the compiler to report the error. However i'd like to know if there is a solid reason that this not be the case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile Views in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To let you detect these errors at compile time, ASP.NET MVC projects now include an MvcBuildViews property, which is disabled by default. To enable this property, open the project file and set the MvcBuildViews property to **true**, as shown in the following example/image below:

```
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

Comment: this is fantastic and a lot of help. I've been struggling with this lately when using MVCContrib and changing the signature of my Controller Actions. However, is there a way that when the errors are displayed, that when you double click on them, they go to the view code rather than the compiled source?

Comment: Is there an option to NOT build views that are NOT included in the project?

Comment: I havn't found such an option @dotjoe. VS simply runs the command `aspnet_compiler.exe` with the path to the site as a parameter. It seems to compile all the view files it finds. I had to change the file type in order to exclude them from MvcBuildView (adding ".old" at the end). Obviously one other alternative is to move the file ;)