# Compile views at build time VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.Net MVC - Compiler Errors in Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757547/asp-net-mvc-compiler-errors-in-views)

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2 with Visual Studio 2010, and I *hate* runtime errors.  Compile errors that only happen when I browse that page are almost as bad.

Is there a way I can have my views compile when I hit build?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does [enabling MvcBuildViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757547#1757604) help?

To enable MvcBuildViews make the following change in your project file

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent found a way, what i do when working with views is to right click the webserver icon in the task bar (when running) that hosts my web application and then choose to browse the page. I then simply edit my view in visual studio, save it and then update the browser (no compile is required when working in views). Unfortunately this doesnt give breakpoint capabilities since its outside the debugger.