# Partial View not loading once made strongly typed

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, strongly-typed-view

**Controller:**

```
namespace AdminPortal.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult ServersTab(AdminPortalModel model)
        {      
            return PartialView("~/Views/Home/ServersTab.cshtml", model.Servers);
        }

        public PartialViewResult _ServerNew()
       {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_ServerNew.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

**View to be loaded:**

```
@using AdminPortal.CustomHelpers;

@model AdminPortal.Models.AdminPortalModel;

<div id="scrollBox">
This 'div' element uses 'overflow:scroll' to create scrollbars whenever the contents of     the 'div' become too large.
</div>
```

**View doing the Loading:**

```
@using AdminPortal.CustomHelpers;

@model IEnumerable<AdminPortal.Models.Server>

...


<div id="NewAndEditButtonWrapper">
    @Ajax.ImageActionLink("../../Images/edit_grey.png", "Edit ==>", "_ServerEdit", "",
        new AjaxOptions
           {
               HttpMethod = "GET",
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               UpdateTargetId = "NewEditSubview"
           },
                new
                {
                    id = "EditButton"
                })
    </div>
<div id="NewEditSubview">
</div>
```

**Custom Ajax Helper:**

```
public static IHtmlString ImageActionLink(this AjaxHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText, string actionName, object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
        builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName, routeValues, ajaxOptions).ToHtmlString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(link.Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)));
    }
```

Essentially, When my "View to be loaded" contains @model AdminPortal.Models.AdminPortalModel; it doesn't load, but when I remove this line it will load. I need this modal so that I can use it in my View to display some information to the user. I am unsure why making the view strongly typed is causing the View not to load. Any advice?

**EDIT:**

To further expand on "doesn't load":
[image: When the View is strongly typed]

[image: When the View was not strongly typed]

Comment: It would make your question easier to answer if you expanded on "doesn't load".

Comment: When I say the View doesn't load, I mean that the partial View wont render to the screen, it is not visible to the user when the view is strongly typed. As soon as I remove this feature, the View becomes visible again.

Comment: Well, the problem Resolved itself, not sure what happened though, so any comments or advice are still appreciated.

Comment: This is just a guess. When you create or modify models you need to actually rebuild the project. So if you had modified the c# model, but were only refreshing the .cshtml page, then that could exhibit the type of problems you encountered. However, I am not entirely sold on that theory - it is just a guess.

Comment: I just figured out the issue, @model AdminPortal.Models.AdminPortalModel; isn't supposed to end in a semicolon. These errors are impossible to catch because VS never accurately displays errors for me, especially in .cshtml files...

Comment: You might want to use fiddler or some tool to catch the responses returned from the server.

Answer (score 0):

> These errors are impossible to catch because VS never accurately displays errors for me, especially in .cshtml files

You can enable compilation of views in ASP.NET MVC projects. This is disabled by default. The property is MvcBuildViews , and needs to be manually modified in the project file. See for answer: [ASP.Net MVC - Compiler Errors in Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757547/asp-net-mvc-compiler-errors-in-views#1757604)