# Web Application Project Deployment VS2010 - Precompile Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate I created a ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Web Application.

I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28WEBAPPLICATIONPROJECTS.PACKAGEPUBLISHOVERVIEW%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29&rd=true.

Its about the new features for Web Application Deployment.
I dont see an option to precompile Views. Also I dont see other options that where available in previous version of Web Deployment Project: ie if the web is compiled into a single assembly or into one assembly per page.

I had the impression that Application Project Deployment is the scuccessor of Web Deployment Project.. maybe I am wrong about it.

How should I precompile views now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc) has an answer that worked for me with MVC 2

Answer (score 0):

It's still in beta, you can [download beta 1 here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=711a2eef-b107-4784-9063-c978edc498cd&displaylang=en).