# MVC - No errors on Visual Studio 2010 compilation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I having a situation with my VS2010, while using MVC, and I would like to know if anyone have the same situation.

My VS2010 don't check if class defined in ASPX pages header exists, or class property in ASPX during compilation.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Compile Views in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for compiling your views:
[Compile Views in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc)