# sending hidden property under different name from razor to the controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

inside razor form I'm sending value using hidden property like

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
```

this way I'm expecting on controller side parameter to be named as `name` in order to fetch this value.

```
 public ActionResult(string MyName)
 {

 }
```

How can I send this value

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
```

under different name, so I can on controller side receive that information like

```
public ActionResult(string MyName)
{

}
```

Comment: I don't see the difference on the samples? Maybe a typo?

Comment: @KarelTamayo I think they are asking how they can send their Hidden, which uses model.Name, to post to the controller's MyName value

Comment: There is really no point using `HtmlHelper`method is this case (the whole point of using the helpers is for correct 2-way model binding, implementing validation etc and your defeating all that) You may as well just manually create the input `<input type="hidden" name="MyName" ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Html.Hidden(), not HiddenFor().  With Hidden you can pass in the name you want the element to be named.

Something like

@Html.Hidden("MyName", Model.Name)

See here

[What is the difference between Html.Hidden and Html.HiddenFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381871/what-is-the-difference-between-html-hidden-and-html-hiddenfor)

Answer (score 3):

If you use set Name attribute same as your parameter then in works fine.

```
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "MyName", name = "MyName"})
```

View Look like
  [image: View]

Controller looks

[image]

Comment: the html prop Name="myName" is case sensitive in the html helper so dont use name="MyName"