# What is the correct way to precompile an ASP.Net MVC 2 application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

What is the correct way to precompile an ASP.Net MVC 2 application from Visual Studio 2010?

I am using asp.net 3.5, and trying to use the post build event.

I am using this;

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler -v / -p "$(ProjectDir)"
```

but it gives me an invalid path error on the ProjectDir.

UPDATE: I changed "$(ProjectDir)" to $(ProjectDir)\ and it now gives me this error;

"It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. "

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you running this as a post-build event?

Comment: Yes, that is what I said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a few different issues going on and fixed them.

1. I used this in my Post Build;

   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler -p "$(ProjectDir)." -v / D:\Work\VSP\deploy
2. Then I was getting strange errors when it tried to compile my aspx pages. It turns out that I had a "hold" folder in my project to hold original copies of some of my pages. The compiler was trying to compile them even thorugh I didnt need them. After removing those files everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

For more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc) answer.

Comment: Yes I did see this, and it was about compiling views, not compiling the entire application. It also was from 2008, MVC 2 was not around at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the absolute path and work from there. What you tried would normally work, although I use the `$(SolutionDir)` property, and go from there, as I run this against many different projects.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs(v=vs.71).aspx) is a list that you may find useful.

Also, I agree with Bugai13. You should upvote/accept answers.

Comment: If this works for me then I will accept it, but if id doesn't then I can't accept it.

Comment: That's why you provide feedback to the user, so that they can help you find an appropriate answer. It's not much of a community if you don't do that.

Comment: You tried `SolutionDir`? It shouldn't be the same error as you're not going outside the application bounds. You'll need to add on your web application directory afterwards. Eg: `$(SolutionDir)\MyMvcApplication`.