# Anyone know what would be causing this mystery compilation error in C# MVC.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It says (note this is during run-time I get this error)... I have no idea what would be causing this, it won't show the source location of the problem:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Compilation Error Description: An
>   error occurred during the compilation
>   of a resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following
>   specific error details and modify your
>   source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1513: }
>   expected
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File:
>   c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\App_Web_builder.aspx.ae291f52.nyh6nefp.0.cs
>   Line: 402
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>
>   "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe"
>   /t:library /utf8output
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\211759e9\5c40d041_0b75ca01\KellermanEncryptionLibrary.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\be498b7b\b02afb41_0b75ca01\BugzScoutDotNet.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\e7d98667\b6a2d241_0b75ca01\MySql.Data.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\ecf072d2\d2f0e041_0b75ca01\weborb.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\b66d72da\86b5e541_0b75ca01\Microsoft.Web.GeneratedImage.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\ca088036\6051b86d_ce2dcb01\WashingtonLibrary.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\0bfc64af\4b9b473c_4349cb01\SoftLayerAPI.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\App_global.asax.c3n8a716.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\2b504f93\e634bcb3_238fca01\Elmah.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\5aeba754\3a7aea41_0b75ca01\nsoftware.InPayPalWeb.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ABCpdf\7.0.1.9__a7a0b3f5184f2169\ABCpdf.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\b1fec446\56c8f841_0b75ca01\Ionic.Zip.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\85597ee3\40f2c141_0b75ca01\nsoftware.InPayPal.System.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\47e2e59b\64b2c372_357fca01\SessionLibrary.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Abstractions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Abstractions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\8b548338\16c08da8_fa21cb01\ChilkatDotNet2.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\94d007bd\64efff41_0b75ca01\Npgsql.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\f4693a8a\a87bcb41_0b75ca01\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\883efa34\20282c43_c2b1cb01\KODmvc.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\df8e12df\beb1b9b7_ee3acb01\AssetCreationLibrary.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\e83a4e44\b626d97b_9039cb01\CKFinder.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\d8c5a0b2\aed1a305_fb7ccb01\nsoftware.IPWorksSSL.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\0cd668f5\0690ac8a_1712cb01\Washington.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\b735fb67\6a67d741_0b75ca01\Mono.Security.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\assembly\dl3\a4146fa8\4e19c941_0b75ca01\ODAEncryptor.DLL"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /out:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\App_Web_builder.aspx.ae291f52.nyh6nefp.dll"
>   /debug- /optimize+
>   /win32res:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\ou-vzbh2.res"
>   /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701
>   /warnaserror- 
>   "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\App_Web_builder.aspx.ae291f52.nyh6nefp.0.cs"
>   "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\App_Web_builder.aspx.ae291f52.nyh6nefp.1.cs"
>
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler
>   version 3.5.30729.1 for Microsoft (R)
>   .NET Framework version 3.5 Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\App_Web_builder.aspx.ae291f52.nyh6nefp.0.cs(402,60):
>   error CS1513: } expected

Comment: Well, it certainly looks like something's missing a brace. Have you looked at `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0715ad11\99446ce5\App_Web_builder.aspx.ae291f52.nyh6nefp.1.cs`?

Comment: You're missing a `}` somewhere in your code. But without the source where it's falling over you might have a job finding it. I take it that there are no compilation errors in VS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, it means you have garbage in a view.  An open { somewhere.

Comment: sure enough, had a ')' where a '}' should have been, thank you

Comment: @Tundey they made it rather annoying that I have to wait in order to mark the answer :/

Answer (score 2):

It was happen when I was assigned value to a variable var desc= @Model.ShortDescription; so that it was happened afterwards I find out solution. I have assigned like this var dd= Model.ShortDescription; then works fine. We don't need to use @ symbol.

**for more details**

[www.infinetsoft.com/Post/-Solved-Complilatio...e-code-appropriately/1202](http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/-Solved-Complilation-error-An-error-occurred-during-the-compilation-of-a-resource-required-to-service-this-request-Please-review-the-following-specific-error-details-and-modify-your-source-code-appropriately/1202)

Answer (score 1):

If you [compile your views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc), you can catch these at compile-time.