# Check for razor errors during build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor

Is there a way for Visual Studio (I'm using 2010) to find errors within razor views during builds, in the same way as other code in a C# project would?

It's just a pain that you can check any errors in your code and think that everything's fine, but it appears that you can't be sure about views unless you go through each one.

BTW I obviously don't code in my views - I'm just talking about HTML or URL extension methods for example.

Comment: I would think this would work exactly the same:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile Views in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try setting MVCBuildViews to true in your project file (i.e. edit your csproj file)

```
 <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

Comment: Weirdly for me, that didn't work in an existing property group. It only worked when  I created a specific property group for it, i.e. `<PropertyGroup>
  <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>`

Comment: What would be more useful is a separate 'Build Views' button that lets me optionally build the project AND the views from time to time - not one or the other all the time. Know any way to do that? (can't see on Google & couldn't find any extensions).

Comment: @niico see @tikall’s response below. You could potentially create a build configuration for this specific task. I’ve never done it so can’t confirm that it works but it certainly sounds like it should/would

Comment: Thanks I'll try it - an extension that gives you 1 button to build a view would be even nicer but I guess that doesn't exist?!

Comment: I can't get the below working (<MvcBuildViews> tags weren't already there as @Tikall says - I had to add them?!)

Comment: @MartinCapodici check and see if your project file has `<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>` somewhere else because it might be overriding the new `<MvcBuildViews>` element

Answer (score 17):

Building views takes a while and the extra 10+ seconds to do a debug build can get annoying fast, so I usually only set the MvcBuildViews to true on release type build configurations.
That way, if you have a build server it will catch the error for you, or you can manually run a release build every now and then to check your views.

I don't think order matters for PropertyGroup elements, but for a more complete example i included elements above and below the MvcBuildViews element.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    ...
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

The MvcBuildViews element in the top PropertyGroup was added by VS on project creation, the build configuration specific one (bottom PropertyGroup) i added manually

Comment: I can't get this to work - <MvcBuildViews> tags weren't already there, I had to manually add them (if that's relevant). My Views have many errors and a build isn't catching them in either configuration.

Comment: I had the same problem as @niico but discovered that it was the PropertyGroup  Condition that did not match my build configuration and platform (condition anyCPU, build x86).

Answer (score 0):

Try add in mode edit of project the following assembly: *System.core*, according to the code:

```
...
<Reference Include="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest" />
...
```

Sometimes this assembler not loader correctly, In My case, it worked!