# Visual Studio 2012, Razor View Errors and Build Succeeded

Tags: visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check for razor errors during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667358/check-for-razor-errors-during-build)

When I compile an ASP.Net MVC 4 project in VS2012, I get the notification

Build Succeeded

whether or not there were build errors related to a Razor View.  The Output tab does not list any errors.  I only see errors related to the Razor view if I check the Error List tab.

Is it possible to have a build error related to a Razor view to trigger a Build Failed rather than Build Succeeded message?

Comment: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-to-detect-errors-of-our-asp-net-mvc-views-on-compile-time-blow-up-in-my-face-theory

Comment: Interesting... but it doesn't work.  The build complains that a copy of web.config on obj/debug/... has an invalid entry for EntityFramework.

Comment: OK.  Well, the term to search for is "Compiled Views."