# Is there a way to enable compiling cshtml templates in a Class Library project on build?

Tags: razor, razorengine

I'm currently using RazorEngine in a non-web application.

I've got a class library that contains the template files, the models used in the templates and a wrapper around RazorEngine to configure it correctly and provide simple template processing.

I've followed the instructions detailing [how to enable intellisense](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/IntellisenseAndResharper.html), and that's working fine.

Currently, when I build the project the build will succeed even if there are errors in the templates. If I open all of the template files then any detected errors will show up in the Error List tab. But even if I build the project with all these files open and the errors in the Error List then the build still succeeds.

If this was a web project I could use "MvcBuildViews" as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667358/check-for-razor-errors-during-build). But since I'm in a class library project I'd assume the build infrastructure that supports that option hasn't been included in the project and so it doesn't effect anything.

I've search about on Google in general and specifically on SO, but I've not managed to find anything about what would be needed to add these build features to my project.

**Getting the errors on build, and preventing the build from succeeding when there are errors is my primary goal.**

Is there a simple way to check for razor errors on build?

Is there a not so simple way to add the required functionality to the build process for the existing project?

Is my only option to start with a web project, then strip out everything I don't need and pretend it's a class library project?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a simple way to check for razor errors on build?

None that I'm aware of. https://github.com/vladimir-shmidt said in Gitter that he compiles the templates at build time and includes the results as resources. But I think the code is not available.

> Is there a not so simple way to add the required functionality to the build process for the existing project?

Depends on your dependencies, but it "should" be quite straightforward:

- Add a new Console Application to your solution
- Reference the project with the Razor templates
- Use `Engine.Razor.Compile` to compile the templates (in the console application)
- Add a build-step to execute the console application

Hope this helps/works,

matthid, a RazorEngine contributor