# MVC System.Web.HttpCompileException on Html.RenderPartial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I'm getting an `System.Web.HttpCompileException` when the my view calls `Html.RederPartial`. The exception message is:

> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

I've checked that the:

- Controller doesn't throw an exception
- Partial view does exist
- The `Model` passed by controller and received by the view is the same.
- The `InnerException` is null

The exception sounds like it should be that the html or razor is malformed or incorrect, but the solution builds fine. It was also working not too long ago, so I'm guessing, I'm missing something silly...

**My question:**

Does anyone know how to know what causes this exception? Or is there a way to get more information on the exception?

**Edit:** Here's the StackTrace

> at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean ...

Comment: How are you trying to call this? Post some code and we might help you. This way is too generic.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out it was a silly mistake on my part. MVC couldn't compile the `Html` from `Razor` because I had renamed a property within my `Model`, but didn't update it in the `.cshtml`.

Turn on Razor Build errors at compile time. Edit your `csproj` file and set the following:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

Thanks to JP for this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667358/check-for-razor-errors-during-build).

Answer (score 0):

I found one of my HTML partial i.e. *.cshtml file was missing references. Generally when any cshtml page having error on it, is not shown at compile time though you can track it with debug points

Answer (score 0):

We resolved " External component has thrown an exception." issue by recycling the application pool. It is quick method before doing else.