# How to pass error message to error view in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on exception handling and have written below code for the same.

**Web.Config**

```
<customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
```

**Code Changes**

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {

        //_logger.Error("Uncaught exception", filterContext.Exception);

        ViewResult view = new ViewResult();
        view.ViewName = "Error";
        filterContext.Result = view;

        // Prepare the response code.
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    // To handle exceptions
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilter());

    var unityContainer = ModelContainer.Instance;
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(unityContainer));
}
```

**Error View**

```
@*@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute*@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>Error</h1>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my error view, I want to show the exception message.

Also I have one more requirement to show different message in case of `404 error` exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : HandleErrorAttribute {
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {

        var controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
        controller.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        controller.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

        var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var exception = filterContext.Exception;
        //need a model to pass exception data to error view
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(exception, controllerName, actionName);

        var view = new ViewResult();
        view.ViewName = "Error";
        view.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
        view.ViewData.Model = model;

        //copy any view data from original control over to error view
        //so they can be accessible.
        var viewData = controller.ViewData;
        if (viewData != null && viewData.Count > 0) {
            viewData.ToList().ForEach(view.ViewData.Add);
        }

        //Instead of this
        ////filterContext.Result = view;
        //Allow the error view to display on the same URL the error occurred
        view.ExecuteResult(filterContext);

        //should do any logging after view has already been rendered for improved performance.
        //_logger.Error("Uncaught exception", exception);

    }
}
```

**Views/Shared/Error.cshtml**

```html
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>Error</h1>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            @{
                if (Model != null && Model.Exception != null) {
                    <h5>Here is some information you can pass on to the administrator</h5>
                    <h3>Path: ~/@string.Format("{0}/{1}", Model.ControllerName, Model.ActionName)</h3>
                    <h4>Error: @Model.Exception.GetType().Name</h4>
                    if (Request.IsLocal) {
                        <h4>Message: @Model.Exception.Message</h4>
                        <h5>@Model.Exception.StackTrace</h5>
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Web.Config**

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Comment: `` view.ExecuteResult(filterContext)`` is throwing exception

Comment: what error is it throwing? Make sure you have the error view in this location in project `Views/Shared/Error.cshtml`

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpCompileException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Ok that error looks like it might be an issue in the error view. check this post and see if you can resolve it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31609192/5233410

Comment: Thanks...System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute doesn't contain definition for ``Exception``, instead it has ``ExceptionType``

Comment: This shows that the property should exist https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorinfo(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Have you added anything extra to what I had in the view in the answer?

Comment: Oh I got it, you apparently wrote ``@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute `` it should be ``@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo``....let me try and will let know in case of issue

Comment: Ouch. my bad. yeah thats the typo. I had copied it from you original question.

Comment: no problem...it is working but displaying the content of error page twice..any idea?

Comment: hmmmm...that is odd. Can you screenshot it and send a link if possible.

Comment: Just want to confirm that in my web.config I have ``<customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>``... Do I need to make any changes?

Comment: yes that should be off. that is the culprit right there

Comment: awesome...it worked :) ..last question will it work for ``404 not found`` too ?

Comment: No that is a separate problem with a different workaround.

Comment: ok thanks...I tried this ``<customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Home/Error"></error>
    </customErrors>`` and it worked for 404 but causing twice error display

Comment: Ask it in another question and send me the link. Don't want to muddy up this answer.

Comment: Involves a `ErrorController`, some custom routes and the `httpErrors` in web config to get away from redirects

Comment: Thanks I have accepted the answer and will ask in separate question tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Added new question :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285429/how-to-handle-404-error-in-config-and-code-in-mvc5

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending like this

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Items["Exception"] = Exception.Message;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I just want to share the easiest way to do it. Just paste this in your **Web.config**

```
 <system.web>
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/home">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error.html"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error.html"/>
  </customErrors>
 <system.web>
```