# How to handle 404 error in config and code in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I have implemented exception handling as mentioned in below link

[How to pass error message to error view in MVC 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246370/how-to-pass-error-message-to-error-view-in-mvc-5/39248096#39248096)

It is working fine. But I have requirement to handle `404 Error`.

How can I do that?

if I use below code,

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Home/Error"></error>
</customErrors>
```

it works well when any `404` error occurs. But in case any other exception occurs then my `error.cshtml` call twice and show same exception `two times`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**web.config**

Turn off custom errors in system.web

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

configure http errors in system.webServer

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
      <clear />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/NotFound" />
      <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Create simple error controller to handle those requests **ErrorContoller.cs**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ErrorController : Controller {
    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult NotFound() {
        var statusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Error() {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        return View();
    }
}
```

configure routes **RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

    //...other routes 

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "404-NotFound",
        url: "NotFound",
        defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "500-Error",
        url: "Error",
        defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error" }
    );

    //..other routes

    //I also put a catch all mapping as last route

    //Catch All InValid (NotFound) Routes
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "NotFound",
        url: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }
    );
}
```

And finally make sure you have views for the controller actions

```
Views/Shared/NotFound.cshtml
Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
```

If there are any additional error you want to handle you can follow that pattern and add as needed. This will avoid redirects and maintain the original http error status that was raised.

Comment: In addition to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246370/how-to-pass-error-message-to-error-view-in-mvc-5/39248096#39248096, I followed your answer to this question...when 404 occurs, it worked well

Comment: However in case of other exception, Model in error page is coming as null because Error() action fires which doesn't send any info to view I think

Comment: Check server last error and see if you can build up model there

Comment: Hi... GetLastError() didn't work. So I used session and it worked well for me...if there is any best way to do the same.

In Error.cshtml ,  if (Session["Error"] != null)
                    { Session.Remove("Error"); }
                    else
                    { Session["Error"] = Model; }

Comment: In errorcontroller,   if ( Session["Error"]!=null)
            {
                HandleErrorInfo obj =(HandleErrorInfo) Session["Error"];
                return View(obj);
            }

Answer (score 2):

If you will define defaultRedirect attribute for customErrors then error.cshtml will be rendered only once in your case:

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Home/Error">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Home/Error"/>
 </customErrors>
```