# Application_Error never reached for 404, if URL does not contain an existing controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this code in my global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    var httpException = exception as HttpException;
    //...
}
```

If I call a URL like this, where `NonExistingNonesense` does not exist:

```
localhost/ExistingArea/ExistingController/NonExistingNonesense
```

Everything is fine. (The code from my global.asax will be called)

But if I call a url like this:

```
localhost/NonExistingNonesense
```

The code never reach the `Application_Error` method.

What could be the problem?

---

I have this in my web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
  <!-- ... -->
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
  <!-- ... -->
<system.webServer>
```

---

Please note:

I know it is possible with

```
<error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/PageNotFound" />
```

The problem is, I need to pass some exception context to my view, so I want to handle this by code.

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/39285920/5233410

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi, the catch all RouteConfig does help me :) Strange that `Application_Error` is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Your ASP.NET code won't fire unless it is invoked by the IIS framework.  By default, IIS will stop any request for a file that does not exist before it reaches your code.  But you can turn this off.

Go into IIS admin and disable the [Invoke handler only if request is mapped to a file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730969(v=ws.10).aspx) option.