# unable to display my custom error page on ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using asp.net MVC5
I created a custom error page under `Views/shared/Error.cshtml` 
I updated the web.config with the following;

`<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Shared/Error.cshtml" />`

I also created an error controller class under Controllers as follows;

```
`public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
}`
```

when I run the application and put invalid URL I do not get my custom error page that i created, i still get the common system error page. what could be cause for not showing it? ... thank you.

Comment: Take a look at an answer I gave and see if it works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285429/how-to-handle-404-error-in-config-and-code-in-mvc5/39285920#39285920

Answer (score 1):

you need to define your error page in web config

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

here's the controller

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    public ViewResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View();
    }
}
```