# How to render a View once you're in the Application_Error event handler without redirecting the user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Supposing your application threw an exception that wasn't within the scope of the [`ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controlleractioninvoker.invokeaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method.

This could happen, for example, if the user typed in a wrong URL that didn't resolve to the name of any existing controller or action.

```
http://www.example.com/doesNotExist
```

That URL would throw an `HttpException` with the status code 404.

You could then handle that in the [`Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication?view=netframework-4.8) object's [`Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.error?view=netframework-4.8) event handler.

```
// Global.asax.cs
public void Application_Error()
{
  HttpException exception = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;

  // do whatever with it
}
```

From here on, is it possible to render an ASP.NET MVC View *without actually redirecting the user to a new URL that will render the view*?

```
// Global.asax.cs
public void Application_Error()
{
  HttpException exception = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;

  // can I *render* a View here?
  // In other words, can I execute a ViewResult here?
  // Can I get back into MVC from here?
  // But without redirecting the user. Just re-writing the Response object?
}
```

All the examples I have seen from here simply set the HTTP `StatusCode` and `StatusDescription` on the `Response` object. I'd like to go back to a `View` from here *without redirecting the user to the View url*.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.6 targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

What is it you're trying to achieve but not redirecting the user to an error page?

Our own implementation of `Application_Error()` traps and logs the error to our database before executing a method on our error controller, but this essentially just redirects the user to a friendly page where we show them relevant information about the error so they can report it, for example;

*Global.aspx.cs*

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        string showerrors = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShowErrors"];
        string appid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"];

        if (showerrors != "Y")
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            var httpex = ex as HttpException;

            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                Response.Clear();
            }
            Server.ClearError();

            if (ex is HttpException && ex.InnerException is ViewStateException)
            {
                Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                return;
            }

            ApplicationError err = new ApplicationError();

            err.ApplicationId = appid;
            err.ErrorCode = httpex == null ? 0 : httpex.GetHttpCode();
            err.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;

            err.UserId = User != null ? User.Identity.Name : null;
            err.IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"];
            err.Referrer = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
            err.Url = Request.Url.ToString();
            err.StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;

            string[] errorstoignore = new string[] { "__VIEWSTATE", "PASSWORD" };

            StringBuilder sbfv = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in Request.Form.AllKeys)
            {
                if (!errorstoignore.Contains(s.ToUpper()))
                {
                    if (sbfv.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sbfv.Append(", ");
                    }
                    if (!s.ToLower().Contains("password"))
                    {
                        sbfv.Append(s + ":" + Request.Form[s] + "\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sbfv.Append(s + ":********" + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            err.FormValues = sbfv.ToString();
            err.ErrorDate = DateTime.Now;

            ApplicationServices asvcs = new ApplicationServices();
            asvcs.AddError(err);

            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
            routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
            routeData.Values["id"] = err.ErrorId;
            routeData.Values["exception"] = ex;

            IController errorsController = new ErrorController();
            var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
            errorsController.Execute(rc);
        }
    }
```

*ErrorController.cs*

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    [NoAntiForgeryCheck]
    public ActionResult Index(int id, Exception exception)
    {
        string errortitle = "Application Error";
        int errid = (exception is HttpException) ? ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode() : 0;
        string msg = exception.Message;

        switch (errid)
        {
            case 0:
                errortitle = "Internal Application Error";
                msg = "See error log or debug";
                break;
            case 400:
                //Bad Request
                errortitle = "Security Violation";
                msg = "The page could not be opened.";
                break;
            case 401:
                //Unauthorized
                errortitle = "Security Violation";
                msg = "The page could not be opened.";
                break;
            case 402:
                //Payment Required
                errortitle = "Payment Required";
                break;
            case 403:
                //Forbidden
                errortitle = "Security Violation";
                msg = "The page could not be opened.";
                break;
            case 404:
                //Not Found
                errortitle = "Navigation Error";
                msg = "The page could not be opened.";
                break;
            case 405:
                //Method Not Allowed
                errortitle = "Security Violation";
                msg = "The page could not be opened.";
                break;
            case 406:
                //Not Acceptable
                errortitle = "Not Acceptable";
                break;
            case 500:
                //Internal Server Error
                errortitle = "Internal Server Error";
                if (exception is HttpAntiForgeryException)
                {
                    errortitle = "Security Violation";
                }
                break;
            case 501:
                //Not Implemented
                errortitle = "Not Implemented";
                break;
            case 502:
                //Bad Gateway
                errortitle = "Bad Gateway";
                break;
        }
        //Generate an error reference
        string appid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"];
        string errorref = appid + id.ToString("00000");
        ViewBag.Id = id;
        ViewBag.ErrorTitle = errortitle;
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = msg;
        ViewBag.IsFullPage = "N";
        ViewBag.ErrorAction = "Please contact your Technical Support Desk quoting reference " + errorref + " to report this error.";
        //ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer == null ? String.Empty : Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString();

        return PartialView();
    }
```

Whether this helps you are not I'm not sure until I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I wanted to render a view directly from the Application_Error event handler without having to invoke an action and without having to redirect the user to a URL/route/action via a 302/301. Your code is invoking an action so it's not what I am looking for. The reason I don't want to have an action is that I don't want my error pages to have URLs. I have already thought of a solution and implemented it. I will post an answer in a few days about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom `HandleErrorAttribute` filter like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246370/how-to-pass-error-message-to-error-view-in-mvc-5). You can customize the shared Errors page by passing the Exception as the model and whatever other view data you'd like, but the url remains the same as the original url.