# ASP.NET - Component licensing and Razor

Tags: asp.net

If I have a library that uses .NET component licensing (such as DevArt's dotconnect) with the new Razor view engine, do I need to produce a special App_Licenses.dll for Razor to work?

Answer (score 1):

I can see you already got the official answer in their forums:

http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=20815&sid=0cdf252bc73af673032cccc6f7443659

> If ASP.NET source files will be
>   compiled at server on user request,
>   you should create a special assembly
>   App_Licenses.dll in the Bin directory
>   of your site:
>   http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/universal/docs/licensing.html#asp.
>
> We have not tested our product with
>   Razor view engine. If you encounter
>   any difficulties, please contact us.

Based on that answer, I think you might not need it if you pre-compile your Razor views
See [Compile Views in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc/542944#542944) (and [Notes on Building Razor Views](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/16/notes-on-building-razor-views.aspx)).