# Html.DisplayFor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am studying a MVC sample. I couldn't wrap my head around the syntax of "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)". In the following code, I understand modelItem is what passed into the view which is an object of IEnumerable`<Runner>`. I am not understanding what does "modelItem => item" mean. In order word, How do you translate this lambda back to normal c# syntax? Thanks

```
@model IEnumerable<Runner>

<div id="Finishers">
   <h4>Finishers</h4>
   <ul id="finihers_female">
     @foreach (var item in Model) {
     <li>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) 
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FinishedTime)
     </li>}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

My MSDN document [DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390.aspx) Kris Ivanov listed doesn't do anything to answer the question. You need to read about Lambda expressions. This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848940/mvc-html-helpers-and-lambda-expressions) on exactly this question might help. Can folks add links to their favorite Lambda tutorials?

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda

Comment: I wonder why this answer was downvoted. It exactly answers the question. The OP has troubles with understanding lambda expressions and expression trees in C# and this answer points it to some useful articles on learning it. I have always thought that one should first learn C# and then jump into some specific application development technology such as ASP.NET, WPF, ...

Answer (score 1):

it is `Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TValue))`, here some info for you [DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(Of TModel, TValue) Method (HtmlHelper(Of TModel), Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TValue)))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390.aspx)

Comment: My MSDN doc doesn't do anything to answer his question on Lambda expressions.