# Asp.net mvc html.DisplayFor syntax in linq/lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently studying asp.net mvc and I just started, I decided to move away from web forms to mvc.

I understand the basics of linq and lambdas but I would just like to know or get a good explanation about this particular syntax.

```
@model IEnumerable<CodeplexMvcMusicStore.Models.Album>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre.Name)
        </td>
```

I would just like to know what is the meaning of `modelItem => item.Genre.Name`

My knowledge on this is that `modelItem` gets the value  `item.Genre.Name` and then it is passed method `Html.DisplayFor()`.

I'm also curious about how do I write the same code without using lambda.

Correct me if I'm wrong I would just like to know the meaning of the code and how it is read.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848940/mvc-html-helpers-and-lambda-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
    @model IEnumerable<CodeplexMvcMusicStore.Models.Album>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Raw(item.Genre.Name)
        </td>
```

Or

```
@model IEnumerable<CodeplexMvcMusicStore.Models.Album>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Genre.Name
        </td>
```

Answer (score 5):

Read this: **[Why All The Lambdas?](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/11/26/why-all-the-lambdas.aspx)** : Good article explaining the use of Lambdas.

The lambda expressions (of type Expression) allow a view author to use strongly typed code, while giving an HTML helper all the data it needs to do the job.