# What does (x => y) mean in MVC view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

So I've been learning **MVC** lately, looking at the one of the views that I generated with `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`, I found this expression `(model => model.name)`.

I tried looking for it but all I got was some math curves and some other things that have no relation with coding.
I was wondering what that means and if possible how it works.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you came across is what is called a `lambda expression`.
I invite you to read the following topics:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx
- [MVC HTML Helpers and Lambda Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848940/mvc-html-helpers-and-lambda-expressions)

You can also google it some more, I'm sure you will find more useful topics.

Comment: thanks a lot, i only needed to name of it because i tried to look but i found nothing, thanks!