# How to make MSBuild in Hudson signal that an ASP.NET MVC View has not been committed to SVN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, view, hudson, commit

I'm using [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) as Continuous Integration Server and Visual Studio's [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) build system.

When I commit new code to the SVN repository, sometimes I forget to add a new view `.cshtml` file just added to the project.

MSBuild won't catch this, that is, I end up with:

```
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

Problem: I'll only see that I forgot to add the view to the project during runtime when I try to access that view.

I have already enabled `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>` in `.csproj` file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc), but it does not solve this problem.

When a View does not exist, Visual Studio signals that with font-color = Red inside an Action method with this message: Cannot resolve view 'ViewName':

[image]

The code still compiles with no errors. This is great, but my case is different: the View is there and I only forgot to commit it.

Hope someone knows how to overcome this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you automate in your build the execution of the Package or Publish target you will get an error for any missing .cshtml files at build time.

See this: http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/02/web-packaging-creating-web-packages.html

Comment: great! I got the error now applying the Package target. Thank you very very much... :D