# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 - Why strong-typing Model in a View, if static compilation is not happening?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, strong-typing, type-safety, strongly-typed-view

I'm actively developing desktop applications, local and network services, some classic ASP.NET, etc., so I'm used to static compilation and static code analysis. Now that I'm (finally) learning [ASP.NET MVC 3.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework#Release_history) I'm seeing that many of the ASP.NET MVC experts and experienced developers are recommending using strongly-typed views in ASP.NET MVC 3.0 (where applicable).

I'm guessing that "strongly-typed" means writing `@model=...` at the top of a view's code. But in doing that I only get [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) to work, no static code checking is taking place. I can write anything I want in the `@model` statement in [cshtml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#Other_files) and it would compile and run. Consequentially, `Model.Anything` also compiles. In fact, if I *don't* type @model I can dynamically use whatever model I want that has "compatible" properties and methods.

I'm used to "strongly-typed" meaning "won't compile", like LINQ to *whatever* just will not compile if you don't get the properties right. Is there any other purpose for `@model` other than IntelliSense and a *run-time* error, and why is it called strong-typed if it's in fact, not?

*[Strong typing, Meanings in computer literature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing#Meanings_in_computer_literature)*

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Although my question is definitely not a duplicate of the one you stated the actual answer might be useful.

Comment: Eranga has actually pointed out a potential answer to what you're asking for. You want compile time validation of Razor views as far as I can tell. The link shows how to set this up.

Comment: @Eranga, yes that's what I said in the first comment, that the answer to the question could apply. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views are compiled at runtime by default. You can modify your project file (csproj) to compile the views when the application builds by setting the following property:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

Downside of this approach is that your buildtime will increase significantly. You should consider only setting this option to true for release builds.

You can edit your project file by unloading the project, right-click the project and choose Edit ProjectFile

Comment: It seems that if my view has `@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Foo>` and I call this view in a controller using `return View("TheView", new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })`, the project compiles without errors even when `MvcBuildViews` is `true in the .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to setup your project so that it includes views in your compilation. This would be where static typing is useful. Another place would be in runtime, if you try to pass in a model that does not match the expected model you will immediately get an exception. If you were to type views dynamically then you would not know your model was invalid until your view tried to access a property of the model and finds out it isn't there.

The second scenario is also a nightmare if you pass in the wrong model object but it happens to have the same named property as the expected model. Then you just get invalid data and debugging becomes hell.

Answer (score 0):

model is new dynamic type in .net 4.0, so these types get resolved at runtime not at compilation time.