# Include aspx in the static analysis (FxCop) of an MVC website

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, fxcop

I am doing static analysis for a MVC v2 website build with .net 4. I have compiled the website and ran FxCop on the resulting dll, but then I realized that the dll does not contain the code in the views (I used a reflector to determine that).

So the question is:

Can one configure the MVC project so that the views are published in a DLL that can be scanned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [precompile views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc) by setting the following in the `.csproj`:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```