# No compile errors generated for inline C# code in web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, aspnet-compiler

I have a aspx web page with no code behind and a few inline C# methods (webmethods) for a mostly static page.

The following lines of code would return a compile time error were it placed in a code behind page (nothing being returned from the method)

```
    <script runat="server">
    [WebMethod]
    public static string SomeMethod()
    {
       string result = "hello";
    }
    </script>
```

Is there a compiler option to turn on the compile time check for inline C# code blocks in a web page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For regular asp.net:

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/compiling-aspx-templates-using.html

for asp.net mvc

[Compile Views in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks - it worked. Also just want to add that using re-sharper helps.