# How to compile MVC3 (razor ) Views including Some java files in Web Project

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc-3, compiler-errors

I want to compile views in my ASP.Net MVC3(razor) Project.
I have used this technique
[Compile Views in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc/542944#542944)

Its working fine but problem is that when i do this, an error starts showing:
**`"The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VJSharp.VJSharpCodeProvider, VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" could not be located."`**

When i dig more i found that this error occur when some *java files* included into project.
I have a printers plugin which is made on java(some `.jar` and other java related file). When i remove these files, everything starts working fine. 
But problem is that, **I cant** remove these java files from my project because these have an important role in my application.

Is there any way that i can compile my Views with including java file into my project?
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Change the build action on the Java files to "none"? Assuming nothing needs to be done to them.

Comment: Some of these java files have Build Action 'None' and Some have 'Content'. None has 'Compile'. According to your suggestion i changed Build Action of all java files to 'None', but nothing happened. The  "The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VJSharp.VJSharpCodeProvider, VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" could not be located." error is still occurring.