# Let graphic designer edit views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

We have graphic/interface designer who is developing html/css for our websites. 
How can I let him work on cshtml and css files without giving him access to controllers and models?
Greetings

Comment: Do you mean give access in source control? Or give access in your IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not separate the Controller and Models into separate Class Library projects, referenced by the MVC project?  That way, you can expose the MVC project, including the views, styles and scripts, but keep the infrastructure private.

So long as you keep the naming convention correct, you shouldn't have any issue with controllers being separate.

Comment: then graphic designer will gain access to the project with views only and won't see controllers in models.. this is what I wanted, but will he be able to compile the project having only views? Sorry if I didn't understand something...

Comment: You might also want to enable compilation of views, so issues are caught at compile time rather than runtime.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it. How should I share these projects with him? Through SVN/GIT or using VS Team Foundation (which afair is not free)?