# Unrecognized attribute 'xmlns:xdt' deployonbuild=true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, web-config-transform

When building my solution consisting of some class libraries and an MVC 4 project from the command line with the DeployOnBuild parameter set to true I am getting the following error when it performs the MvcBuildViews step.

```
 error ASPCONFIG: Unrecognized attribute 'xmlns:xdt'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
```

I have done some searching around and cannot find a solution. I have added this as a pre-build step and it does not help.

```
del $(ProjectDir)obj\* /F /S /Q
```

Although this pre-build step is needed to stop it creating this error when I perform a normal build.

Let me know if you need more details, any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810145/web-config-error-unrecognized-attribute-xmlnsxdt-note-that-attribute-names

Comment: Maybe my answer to this problem on another SO thread solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22981877/115070