# Unrecognized attribute 'xmlns' in custom .config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I've created a custom `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection` which I'm keeping in a separate config file and including it into my web.config via `'configSource="MyCustomConfigFile.config"'`

I've also created a .xsd schema for the custom config file to add some goodies like schema validation / intellisense - which works nicely.

When attempting to start the application (Which is hosted in IIS8, .NET 4.5.1)
I'm getting the following error :

> Configuration Error    Description: An error occurred during the
> processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
> Please review the specific error details below and modify your
> configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'xmlns'. Note that
> attribute names are case-sensitive.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
>
> Line 2: **<identityServer xmlns="http://myCustomNamespace.xsd">**

To be honest, I'm surprised - can anyone tell me how to fix this without removing the xmlns so that I can retain the schema validation/intellisense?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the information found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/288d269d-3cdc-4013-a21b-8b533b784496/how-to-add-schemaintellisense-for-custom-sections-in-appconfig-?forum=xmlandnetfx) It became clear that the parser is failing to deserialize the config section due to the fact that the config section is not aware of the 'xmlns' attribute - which actually makes PERFECT sense.

In order to fix this you can add the following to your custom configuration section in C# :

```
    public class MyCustomConfigurationSection
    {
private const string XmlNamespaceConfigurationPropertyName = "xmlns";
    [ConfigurationProperty(XmlNamespaceConfigurationPropertyName, IsRequired = false)]
            public string XmlNamespace
            {
                get
                {
                    return (string)this[XmlNamespaceConfigurationPropertyName];
                }
                set
                {
                    this[XmlNamespaceConfigurationPropertyName] = value;
                }
            }
    }
```

This fixes the issue completely.

Comment: Also you should add properties for "xmlns:xsi" and "xsi:schemaLocation" if you want to specify location of your xsd schema.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Is this the only way that you've found to remedy this issue? I mean this works fine, but seems like there should be an easier way!

Comment: That's the only way that I'm aware of

Comment: This well-written answer seems to be based in using the proper asp.net mechanisms to extend web.config in a robust way.  Just my opinion - and I am trying to work this out on a legacy project I am reviving - which has a 3rd-party package that is utilizing configuration aspects of web.config.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered this particular problem myself but you could try deleting the "obj" folder in your project and rebuilding as suggested in the following post.
[Web.config transformation: Unrecognized attribute 'xmlns:xdt'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737984/web-config-transformation-unrecognized-attribute-xmlnsxdt-note-that-attribu)

Comment: @Peter Evans - I see that you want to be helpful, and that is the right idea.  If you are making suggestions that might help the person, and are not well-defined steps to the actual solution - you might want to post them as comments to the original question - where the person with the problem and confirm/deny that your suggestion is helpful.  Posting these comments to the question help clarify the situation, and will not likely earn you down votes.  Hope this is helpful to you.