# Error in Web.Config adding NotFoundMvc in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I got this error after I added **NotFoundMvc** in my project. If I remove **NotFoundMvc**  I don't get this error. What should I change in Web.Config file?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web.config transformation: Unrecognized attribute 'xmlns:xdt'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737984/web-config-transformation-unrecognized-attribute-xmlnsxdt-note-that-attribu)

Comment: sorry to say sir but that link didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check the given line is there within the top of your transform file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

If it is there, I would also check that the following is not within your actual transformed web.config.

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
```

I have found the **web essentials** extension invaluable for resolving errors like this before I deploy.

You can simply right-click your transform file and select preview from Visual Studio and if you encounter any problems you can investigate/fix locally.

**[Web essentials 2012](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebEssentials2012)**

Comment: This solved my problem. Can you please explain why should      xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"                      be removed? Thanks sir.

Comment: That line should not in your primary web.config file. This is the line for a web.config transformation file. Basically, when you create a new project, you will get a Web.config file with one or more sub web.config files named according to the build profiles for your solution.

Comment: Your parent web.config file should start with <configuration> and none of the xmlns:xdt stuff. Your sub web.config files (those used for transforming your parent web.config file) should start with that line.