# MVC 'Find' method taking a long time (even in release)? (Using miniprofile)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using MiniProfile to try and figure out why my MVC site is taking a long time. It looks like the 'Find' method is where the time is being spent. I have read a couple things on this and most people seemed to suggest that it was due to having `<compilation debug="true" .. >` set in the web.conf. I can confirm that in the following example the debug is not set (my compilation looks like the following):

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
   ...
</compilation>
```

No where is debug mentioned. But yet, my find calls are taking upwards of three seconds :S

[image: MiniProfiler]

Any suggestions on how I can figure this out? (Note: I am running on an Azure production server. I have RDC'd into the system to confirm that the pushed web.config does not contain the debug="true").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the first request coming to your website after publishing or after the AppDomain has been brought down by IIS it is normal that the Find method takes a long time. It will then cache the location for this view and on subsequent requests it should be much faster. Try <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>ing in your browser on the same url.

Also try explicitly setting `debug="false"` in your `web.config`.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc) to compile your views when you compile you app.  This should help with the first request to the view.