# How can I include view files from another project when compiling views?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild

The project file already has the recommended way of doing this from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/542944).  However, that isn't enough for our case.  We happen to have shared views in another project.  Several files use shared .master pages that cause compilation errors when attempting to use aspnet_compiler.

I tried accomplishing it this way:

```xml
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TempFolder>$(ProjectDir)\..\temp</TempFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" TargetPath="$(TempFolder)" PhysicalPath="other views location" />
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" TargetPath="$(TempFolder)" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>
```

It turns out aspnet_compiler requires the `TargetPath` folder to be empty, so this is a no go.  Trying it with just the `VirtualPath` and no `TargetPath` doesn't work because the `VirtualPath` is temporary and doesn't carry over to the second compiler call.

Is there any way of accomplishing this?  We could obviously copy over the master pages to this project, but that isn't exactly a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to compile the Razor views into the DLL so that they'll be available to any application the references that DLL. The Razor team has created [Razor Generator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) for this purpose.

Comment: This project happens to use the old aspx engine (hence the .master files).  Is there an equivalent for that?  It is far too big to consider converting it to Razor.

Comment: Not that I know of. Sorry.