# Is there a tool for compile time checking of MVC links?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've inherited a kludgy and buggy MVC code base from another developer, and I'm trying to clean it up.  One thing that would be very helpful would be a tool to check, at compile time, for links that don't correspond to action methods in a controller.

For instance, you can write an action method like this:

```
public ActionResult InsertAccount(string Name)
```

and there could be a link somewhere that looks like this:

```
/SomeController/InsertAccount?Id=Foo
```

Somewhere along the way, the parameter got changed from "Id" to "Name", and this breaks the link.  If everything were in C#, the compiler would catch it, but because the link is generated from strings, a change like this can't be detected.

Is there any tool that would do this, or guidelines for link construction to preserve name safety, so I can use the compiler to catch this kind of problem?

Answer (score 6):

Check out [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/)

With it you can write this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Insert Account", MVC.SomeController.InsertAccount("Foo"))
```

You still will not get a compilation error when you build since Views are not compiled by default. however, you can change this in the project file as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/542944/894273)

Comment: Ooh, that looks great!  Will check it out.

Answer (score 3):

JetBrain's resharper offers this type of checking. It offers quite a bit of help when dealing with the links between views and controllers, it shows you when you try to return a non-existing view and in the view it detects non-existing actions