# How can I make builds fail in VS 2013 if there's a razor/C# error in a .cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to asp.net mvc. I see nasty little red underlines on my .cshtml page in some razor code with errors in the error list, but the project still builds. Can I fail the project build somehow if these errors are about?

As an aside, if I rename a variable in a c# class referred to in a razor page, why doesn't the refactor tool extend its reach to the cshtml file?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to set in your project to compile views during build.

Set in your MVC project:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

All you have to do is **unload** or close the mvc project in Visual Studio, edit the `.cspoj` file (in VS or notepad or your favourite editor), locate `<MvcBuildViews>`  and change the value to `true`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: can you set this in the .csproj.user file?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that his only works for strongly typed views?

Comment: @TorbenRahbekKoch, in most cases, YES, you are correct. But your code errors can be in some code you enter in the Razor view.

Comment: I cant find <MvcBuildViews> !!!

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: Could you have this set up for your local machine, but not set up for production without having to change the proj file for either scenario?

Comment: @Charkins12  AFAIK you can do it only editing project file. I don't know how to do it using the release profiles.

Answer (score 4):

It could be smart using the MvcBuildViews setting only for Release builds, assuming your build process uses a Release build before you deploy. This will remove the extra wait to compile the views when you’re developing and debugging, but still keeps a check in place before you deploy. Add the MvcBuildViews node to the PropertyGroup node for Release builds only. It will look something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>
```

http://blog.falafel.com/get-compile-time-view-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: I had to do exactly this for a different reason, actually. The builder in deploy mode was throwing nonexistent errors from the asp compiler. So, I use MvcBuildViews only on Release mode. This is checked every time I commit anyway.

Comment: There's a discussion of that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665470/why-wont-my-msbuild-deploy-work-after-i-check-precompile-during-publishing-on