# Why won't my msbuild deploy work after I check "Precompile during publishing" on the publish properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, msbuild, publish

I checked the middle option, below, "Precompile during publishing".

[image]

This changed the FDeploy.pubxml file by a few lines. Fine. I committed this single change to my build server.

Heres the pubxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\Temp</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The remote build with mvcbuildviews enabled passed. The remote deploy failed with errors like:

```
Error   82  The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
Error   5   The name 'model' does not exist in the current context
```

and so on. There's over 100 errors like this. Keep in mind the regular msbuildviews enabled msbuild step worked fine with the same code.

I use msbuild on the web project csproj this way:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FDeploy /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /p:Configuration=Release
```

Any clues? Oh yeah, checking the box caused the same errors on my dev machine as well, I had to delete the bin, obj and appdata folders completely to neutralize it. However, doing a fresh checkout on the build server did not help.

Also note that when I went back to my old deploy profile it took a fresh checkout to fix the deploy.

Comment: Same issue, any headway?

Comment: unfortunately not, but sooner or later I'll have to solve this, I'll keep you informed

Comment: @Mark Lopez - found a solution, but perhaps not one you would like, mark.

Comment: that was my solution as well. I believed it to be an issue with one of our build targets, although running with debug symbols actually ended up helpful in production so we opted to keep it.

Comment: it's annoying that when I deploy it does something to bin, obj, or appdata that screws up future "debug" builds from the same checkout. Mvcbuildviews totally fails and gives all kinds of crazy errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had to cheat to solve this problem: I restricted my use of MvcBuildViews to only the 'Debug' version of the project:

In the csproj file:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I ran into other inexplicable errors using mvcbuildviews when deploying. Seems best to avoid using it altogether. Anyway, the build is still kept clean because I compile and test the debug version too.