# Missing reference after copying view folder from one project to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Ok.  In an effort to save time rather than Add => Existing Item I simply compied the view folder from one MVC project to another.  Now site will build but not error when I try to view any page.

From compiler full error report:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'CopiedFromMVCWebApplication' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 26:     using System.Web.Optimization; Line 27:     using
>   System.Web.Routing; Line 28:     using CopiedFromMVCWebApplication;
>   Line 29:     using CopiedToMVCWebApplication;

I thought this was a simple error to fix, did a find for "CopiedFromMVCWebApplication" and found no text with that name.  I looked at every file in the view folder I copied into but not reference to the "CopiedFromMVCWebApplication" namespace exists.

I searched online for the error code, but what I found was just fixes to something simple like mispelling the namespace or not referencing but not including a using statement for some assembly.

Notes:  Using Visual Studio Pro [Yes, properly licensed], MVC 5, EF 6.

Comment: Did you miss the web.config that's supposed to be in the View folder root?

Comment: I copied it across to the new project, and selected "Replace All" when the dialogue prompted me to overwrite or make a copy.  Looking at the web.config now and it looks normal.  No references to the old project, but has all the <add namespace ... references I am used to seeing

Comment: Have you copied only VIEWS? Is so can you share view code on which you got error? This error might be because of Models you are using on view s which you copied are not existing or not in the same namespace. Share your code, then we can think so solving your problem , or else we might end up guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use compiled views so that you can have compilation error rather than runtime error.
refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936737/900096 to use compiled view.