# How to identify unused classes in C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I've a **C#** big solution that contains different projects. It contains also a batch with a Main static method.
I have to identify and remove all the classes that can't be used starting from this method.
Which is the best way to do that?
I'm using Microsoft **Visual Studio Professional 2015**

Thanks!

Comment: Resharper, maybe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no tools which can do this completely, because

- System.Reflection and System.CodeDom exist - [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments)
- New C# code can be generated at run-time, which uses otherwise-unused classes.
- No tools can predict what that new C# code is (apart from the humans who wrote the code)
- Dependency Injection libraries (which use System.Reflection behind the scenes) can call "unused" classes. This happens frequently with MVC Controller classes.
- Razor Views can use classes. These are not compiled by default. Instead, they will crash at runtime if a class is missing.

Assuming no-one is using System.Reflection, you could do it by hand.

For each class:

- Select it in Visual Studio, right-click then "Find All References"
- If none found, comment the class out /* */
- Rebuild all ([including Razor views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc)). If no errors found, then the class is unused.

Comment: Yes, you're right. In this case no-one is using reflection. The work of finding the references and rebuild for each class is very heavy. I was looking for a faster solution. I've tried with Resharper (right click on the method -> Inspect -> Outgoing calls). Now I have a tree of used classes, I need a list of classes that are in solution but not in the tree, so I can remove them.

Comment: Time for old-school: a texteditor and a spreadsheet. Copy your tree into the text-editor, remove any junk so just the names are left. Copy/paste into spreadsheet, then sort alphabetically. In VisualStudio, Find In Files for "public class ", copy the output to a text-editor. Again, remove everything except the class name, copy to spreadsheet, sort. Compare the two spreadsheets :-) If there are duplicates, check those by hand (different namespaces)

Comment: I tried but the export format is very bad :( I think that the only way is to do all manually as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth downloading and starting the free trial of [resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). By using the "Solution-Wide Analysis" feature, you will be able to quickly find code that is not used anywhere in the solution. Plus there are loads of other cool features too!

Comment: I've tried with Resharper (right click on the method -> Inspect -> Outgoing calls). Now I have a tree of used classes, I need a list of classes that are in solution but not in the tree, so I can remove them.

Comment: Try this: Resharper menu -> Inspect -> Code Issues in Solution. There will be lots of stuff you don't care about, but it should also pick up on stuff that isn't being used. (edit) use the Filter command at the top of the Inspection Results screen, first Uncheck All, and then check "Class is never instantiated" under the "Potential Code Quality Issues" group.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but the list contains a lot of classes that are used but not instantieted (i.e. classes that contains constants). I think that the only way is do all by hand :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try by right click and check the references. It is possible for methods, classes and properties as well . But it won't show if the class, method or property referenced in presentation layer

Comment: I know but the problem is that a class can be referenced by another that is not part of the batch. I need to create a "tree" of used classes starting by the main method and than identify all the classes that aren't in the tree and that I can remove from the projects.

Comment: @TeoVr81: That sounds like a fairly manual process then.  Since you could have lots of classes which reference each other but don't happen to be referenced by that one entry point.

Answer (score 0):

The below code can be used with the `FxCopCmd.exe` command line executable. `FxCopCmd.exe` comes part of the default `Visual Studio` installation. First you have to setup a new project and compile the code into a DLL.

In Visual Studio, create a new `Class Library` project. Pick a name like `FxCopDemo`. It must target `.NET Framework 4` or newer. During compilation, a warning message will be displayed about the build. The warning message can be fixed by changing `Properties > Build > Platform target` to `x86`.

In the project, add references to:

- `FxCopSdk.dll`
- `Microsoft.Cci.dll`

Depending on your `Visual Studio` version, the DLLs are located in a folder such as:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\` or
- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\`

Make sure to do a `Debug build` so that the program database (PDB) files are generated. The `PDB` files will supply `FxCop` with the debugging information it needs output the line numbers from the source code.

Copy and paste this XML into a file named `UnusedCodeXml.xml` and add it to the project as an existing item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Rules FriendlyName="">

<Rule TypeName="UnusedClassesRule" Category="UnusedCode" CheckId="UC0001">
    <Name>A class or class cluster is not referenced by the main code.</Name>
    <Description>
A class is included as part of an executable, or class library, but that code is not used.
    </Description>
    <Url></Url>
    <Resolution Name="Orphan">The class '{0}' is not referenced by any other classes.</Resolution>
    <Resolution Name="Cluster">The class '{0}' is only referenced by classes in an isolated cluster.</Resolution>
    <MessageLevel Certainty="95">Warning</MessageLevel>
    <Email></Email>
    <FixCategories>NonBreaking</FixCategories>
    <Owner></Owner>
</Rule>

</Rules>
```

**Important:** After adding the XML rule file to the project. Then right-click on the item, goto `Properties`, and change the `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`.

Note: The `C#` code is just a little too long to fit in this post together, so the code is posted below. Copy and paste the `C#` code in my other answer into a file named `UnusedClassesRule.cs`. Add the file to the project. Compiling the project should create a file called `C:\Projects\FxCopDemo\bin\Debug\FxCopDemo.dll`.

Now open a `Command Prompt` window, and go to the directory that contains the `FxCopCmd.exe` executable. `FxCopCmd.exe` seems a little finicky with the order the arguments are passed in. It seems like `/d:` has to be specified last when used.

Case 1) Analyze a single executable, i.e. `MyProgram.exe`. The command line for that would be:

`FxCopCmd "/f:C:\Projects\MyProgram\bin\Debug\MyProgram.exe" /r:C:\Projects\FxCopDemo\bin\Debug\FxCopDemo.dll /out:c:\temp\refs.csv /q /c`

- `/f:` is the path to the exe to analyze
- `/r:` is the path to the rule dll
- `/out:` optional. saves the output to the specified file
- `/q` means quiet
- `/c` optional. Outputs the results to the console.
- `/v` optional. Verbose. If specified, a list of all references each class has will be included in the output.

Case 2) You have a project that compiles into a `DLL` and an `EXE`. In this case, copy the files `MyProgram.exe`, `MyProgram.Core.dll`, and PBD files into a separate subfolder, e.g. `\bin\Debug\fxcop\`. The `/f:` argument will point to the subfolder.

`FxCopCmd /f:C:\Projects\MyProgram\bin\Debug\fxcop\ /r:C:\Projects\FxCopDemo\bin\Debug\FxCopDemo.dll /out:c:\temp\refs.csv /q /c /d:"C:\Projects\MyProgram\bin\Debug\"`

In this case, an extra `/d:` argument is required. It points to the main `Debug` folder, which will probably contain third party DLLs that you don't want to include in the analysis, but are required by `FxCop`.

Here is a screenshot of the sample output. It outputs any classes that aren't referred to by other classes, as well as it detects classes that are disconnected from the rest of the code.

[image: Sample Output]

Finally, the following document is helpful to troubleshoot any issues with `FxCop`:

https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.466.282&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the `UnusedClassesRule.cs` class:

```
using Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FxCopDemo {

[Flags]
public enum CodeLocation {
    StaticInitializer           = 4096,
    ConstructorParameter        = 1,
    ConstructorBody             = 2,
    //---
    MethodParameter             = 4,
    MethodBody                  = 8,
    MethodReturnType            = 16,
    StaticMethodBody            = 2048,
    MethodDef                   = 8192,
    ClassDef                    = 16384,
    //---
    PropertyReturnType          = 32,
    PropertyGetterBody          = 64,
    PropertySetterBody          = 128,
    //---
    EventDelegate               = 256,
    //---
    MemberVariable              = 512,
    StaticVariable              = 1024
}

public class RefItem {

    ///<summary>All the locations in the source code where the full name is referenced.</summary>
    public CodeLocation Locations = (CodeLocation) 0;

    ///<summary>The full name of the class, struct, or enum.</summary>
    public readonly String FullName;

    ///<summary>The total number of times the FullName is referenced by the ClassTypes.</summary>
    public int Count;

    public RefItem(String fullName) {
        this.FullName = fullName;
    }
}

// for each custom class, maintain a collection of all types that the class references
public class Class2 : IComparable<Class2> {

    ///<summary>List of other class types that have a direct reference to this class. This list is populated at the very end.</summary>
    public List<Class2> Nbors = new List<Class2>();

    ///<summary>The full name of this class, struct, or enum type.</summary>
    public readonly String FullName;

    ///<summary>If this class is a nested class, the DeclaringType is the full name of the immediate host.</summary>
    public readonly String DeclaringType;

    ///<summary>The full name of the immediate parent.</summary>
    public readonly String BaseType;

    ///<summary>True if this class contains the Main(...) entry point method.</summary>
    public readonly bool IsEntryPoint;

    ///<summary>The type of node, typically Class, Interface, DelegateNode, EnumNode. Used for reporting purposes.</summary>
    public readonly NodeType NodeType;

    private Dictionary<String, RefItem> dict = new Dictionary<String, RefItem>();

    public Class2(String fullName, bool isEntryPoint, String declaringType, String baseType, NodeType nodeType) {
        this.FullName = fullName;
        this.IsEntryPoint = isEntryPoint;
        this.DeclaringType = declaringType;
        this.BaseType = baseType;
        this.NodeType = nodeType;
    }
    
    ///<summary>
    ///Adds a reference to a class that this class directly references.
    ///<param name="fullName">The full name of the class that this class references.</param>
    ///<param name="loc">The location in the code where the reference occurs. CodeLocation is a [Flags] enum, so multiple locations can exist.</param>
    ///</summary>
    public void Add(String fullName, CodeLocation loc) {
        // variables passed with 'ref' or 'out' as method parameters have an '@' as the last character of the fullName
        fullName = fullName.TrimEnd('@');
        lock(dict) {
            RefItem ri = null;
            if (!dict.TryGetValue(fullName, out ri)) {
                ri = new RefItem(fullName);
                dict[fullName] = ri;
            }
            ri.Locations = (ri.Locations | loc);
            ri.Count++;
        }
    }

    public RefItem GetRef(String fullName) {
        RefItem ri = null;
        dict.TryGetValue(fullName, out ri);
        return ri;
    }

    public List<RefItem> GetRefs() {
        return dict.Values.OrderBy(r => r.FullName).ToList();
    }

    public override String ToString() {
        return FullName;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Class2 other) {
        return String.Compare(this.FullName, other.FullName);
    }
}


/*
For each type node, detect all other types it references.

Then for each node, determine the other nodes that point to it.

Report:
1. Any nodes that aren't pointed to, and
2. Any groups of nodes that are not connected to the main entry point.

Limitations:
1. Seems like when an enum is cast to a int value, the original enum type is not recoverable
   e.g: int x = (int) MyEnum.SomeValue; // seems like the compiler replaces the MyEnum.SomeValue reference with the literal value
   This means that some enums may be reported as unused, but they are actually used.

2. Unreachable code is reported as unused. Not sure how to access unreachable code using the FxCop api.
3. Does not account for reflection that uses hard coded string names.

The following are too granular and are not reported in this rule:
1. Methods (instance or static) that are never called.
2. Variables (properties or fields, instance or static) in classes not used.
3. Variables in method arguments not used.
*/
public class UnusedClassesRule : BaseIntrospectionRule {

    private static Dictionary<String, Class2> dictTypes = new Dictionary<String, Class2>();

    // The multi-threads in FxCop make it hard to debug. The messages are grouped by thread when debugging of this rule is needed.
    private static Dictionary<int, StringBuilder> dictOutput = new Dictionary<int, StringBuilder>();

    private Class2 currentC2 = null;
    private CodeLocation currentLoc = (CodeLocation) 0;
    private Member currentMember = null;
    private bool writeCheckMemberError = true;
    private bool writeVisitExpressionError = true;

    public UnusedClassesRule() : base("UnusedClassesRule", "FxCopDemo.UnusedCodeXml", typeof(UnusedClassesRule).Assembly) {
    }

    public override TargetVisibilities TargetVisibility {
        get {
            return TargetVisibilities.All;
        }
    }

    // Note: BeforeAnalysis() and AfterAnalysis() are called multiple times, one for each rule instance.
    // According to a forum post on MSDN, one rule instance is created for each CPU core.
    //public override void BeforeAnalysis() {
        //base.BeforeAnalysis();
        //MethodCollection list = CallGraph.CallersFor((Method) null);
    //}

    public override void AfterAnalysis() {
        base.AfterAnalysis();
        lock(dictTypes) {
            if (dictTypes.Count == 0)
                return;

            try {
                FinalAnalysis();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                writeCheckMemberError = false;
                Write("Error: " + ex.GetType().FullName + ": " + ex.Message, null, true);
                Write(ex.StackTrace, null, true);
            }
            dictTypes.Clear();      
        }
    }

    public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member) {
        try {
            CheckInternal(member);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (writeCheckMemberError) {
                writeCheckMemberError = false;
                Write("Error: " + ex.GetType().FullName + ": " + ex.Message);
                Write(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
        return this.Problems;
    }

    private ProblemCollection CheckInternal(Member member) {
        Class2 ct = currentC2;
        
        AttributeNodeCollection attribs = member.Attributes;
        for (int i = 0; i < attribs.Count; i++) {
            AttributeNode a = attribs[i];
            Add(ct, a.Type, CodeLocation.MethodDef);
        }

        if (member is Method) {
            currentMember = member;

            var m = (Method) member;
            if (m.ReturnType != FrameworkTypes.Void)
                Add(ct, m.ReturnType, CodeLocation.MethodReturnType);

            if (m.NodeType == NodeType.InstanceInitializer)
                currentLoc = CodeLocation.ConstructorBody;
            else if (m.NodeType == NodeType.StaticInitializer)
                currentLoc = CodeLocation.StaticInitializer;
            else
                currentLoc = (m.IsStatic ? CodeLocation.StaticMethodBody : CodeLocation.MethodBody);

            for (int i = 0; i < m.Parameters.Count; i++) {
                Parameter p = m.Parameters[i];
                TypeNode ty = p.Type;
                Add(ct, ty, CodeLocation.MethodParameter);
            }

            // the DeclaringType is needed when an extension method is called
            Add(ct, m.DeclaringType, currentLoc);

            VisitMethod(m);
            //VisitBlock(m.Body);
            //VisitStatements(m.Body.Statements);
        }
        else if (member is PropertyNode) {  
            var pn = (PropertyNode) member;
            if (pn.Setter != null) {
                currentMember = member;
                currentLoc = CodeLocation.PropertySetterBody;
                VisitStatements(pn.Setter.Body.Statements);
            }
            if (pn.Getter != null) {
                Add(ct, pn.Getter.ReturnType, CodeLocation.PropertyReturnType);
                currentMember = member;
                currentLoc = CodeLocation.PropertyGetterBody;
                VisitStatements(pn.Getter.Body.Statements);
            }
        }
        else if (member is Field) {
            var f = (Field) member;
            var loc = (f.IsStatic ? CodeLocation.StaticVariable : CodeLocation.MemberVariable);
            Add(ct, f.Type, loc);
        }
        else if (member is EventNode) {
            var evt = (EventNode) member;
            Add(ct, evt.HandlerType, CodeLocation.EventDelegate);
        }
        else {
            Write("UNKNOWN CHECK MEMBER: " + member.GetType().FullName + "   full name: " + member.FullName);
        }

        return this.Problems;
    }

    private static void Add(Class2 ct, TypeNode ty, CodeLocation loc) {
        // Given a TypeNode, it may have to be drilled down into determine it's actual type
        // It's also possible that a single TypeNode results in multiple references. For example,
        // public class MyList<T> { ... }
        // public static void Foo<U>(MyList<U> list) where U : Bar {}
        // which should result in adding namespace.MyList, and namespace.Bar

        Stack<TypeNode> stack = new Stack<TypeNode>();
        stack.Push(ty);
        while (stack.Count > 0) {
            ty = stack.Pop();
            if (ty == null)
                continue;

            if (ty.IsGeneric) {
                // otherwise Nullable`1 shows up in the list of references
                if (ty.Template != null && ty.Template != FrameworkTypes.GenericNullable)
                    ct.Add(ty.Template.FullName, loc);

                if (ty.TemplateArguments != null) {
                    foreach (TypeNode ta in ty.TemplateArguments)
                        stack.Push(ta);
                }
                if (ty.TemplateParameters != null) {
                    foreach (TypeNode tp in ty.TemplateParameters)
                        stack.Push(tp);
                }
            }
            else if (ty.IsTemplateParameter) {
                // this is the case when a constraint is placed on a generic type, e.g. public static void Foo<T>(U input) where U : Bar { ... }
                // ty.FullName will be something like "parameter.T"
                // The BaseType == "Bar". If no constraint is specified, then BaseType == "System.Object".
                // The reason it's pushed on the stack is because it could be a constraint like where : U : MyList<Bar> { ... }
                stack.Push(ty.BaseType);
            }
            else if (ty is ArrayType) {
                ArrayType ty2 = (ArrayType) ty;
                TypeNode ty3 = ty2.ElementType;
                ct.Add(ty3.FullName, loc);
            }
            else {
                ct.Add(ty.FullName, loc);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void VisitExpression(Expression exp) {
        try {
            VisitExpressionInternal(exp);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (writeVisitExpressionError) {
                writeVisitExpressionError = false; // only record the first error
                Write("Error: " + ex.GetType().FullName + ": " + ex.Message, null, true);
                Write(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }

    private void VisitExpressionInternal(Expression exp) {
        if (exp == null)
            return;

        Stack<Expression> stack = new Stack<Expression>();
        stack.Push(exp);

        while (stack.Count > 0) {
            exp = stack.Pop();
            if (exp == null)
                continue;

            if (exp is NaryExpression) {
                // this handles Construct, ConstructArray, MethodCall, Indexer
                var ne = (NaryExpression) exp;
                foreach (Expression e in ne.Operands) {
                    stack.Push(e); // the actual arguments
                }
            }

            TypeNode ty = exp.Type;
            bool alert = false;
            if (exp is Variable || exp is Local) { // Note: Local extends Variable
                Add(currentC2, ty, currentLoc);
                //Write("VARIABLE NAME: " + ((Variable) exp).Name.Name + "  " + exp);
            }
            else if (exp is Literal) {
                var lit = (Literal) exp;
                Add(currentC2, ty, currentLoc);
                Object val = lit.Value;
                if (val is TypeNode)
                    Add(currentC2, (TypeNode) val, currentLoc);
                else if (val != null) {
                    // val == null when there is an assignment like, MyClass c = null;
                    Type ty2 = val.GetType();
                    bool isKnown = (ty2.IsPrimitive || ty2 == typeof(String));
                    if (isKnown) {
                        currentC2.Add(ty2.FullName, currentLoc);
                    }
                    else {
                        Write("val.GetType(): " + ty2.FullName);
                        alert = true;
                    }
                }

                //if (val is EnumNode) {
                //  var en = (EnumNode) val;
                //  en.UnderlyingType; // this is the primitive type that the Enum extends, typically int32
                //}
            }
            else if (exp is MethodCall) {   
                var mc = (MethodCall) exp;
                stack.Push(mc.Callee);
            }
            else if (exp is Construct) {
                Add(currentC2, ty, currentLoc);
                var c = (Construct) exp;
                stack.Push(c.Constructor); // c.Constuctor is MemberBinding
            }
            else if (exp is Indexer) {
                var ix = (Indexer) exp;
                Add(currentC2, ix.ElementType, currentLoc); 
                stack.Push(ix.Object);
            }
            else if (exp is AddressDereference) {
                var ad = (AddressDereference) exp; // nullable type
                TypeNode ty2 = ad.Type;
                Add(currentC2, ty2, currentLoc);
                stack.Push(ad.Address);
            }
            else if (exp is MemberBinding) {
                var mb = (MemberBinding) exp;
                stack.Push(mb.TargetObject);
                if (mb.BoundMember is Method) { // Note: InstanceInitializer is a Method
                    var m = (Method) mb.BoundMember;
                    Add(currentC2, m.DeclaringType, currentLoc);
                    CodeLocation loc = (mb.BoundMember is InstanceInitializer ? CodeLocation.ConstructorParameter : currentLoc);
                    for (int i = 0; i < m.Parameters.Count; i++) {
                        Parameter p = m.Parameters[i];
                        TypeNode ty2 = p.Type;
                        Add(currentC2, ty2, loc);
                    }
                }
                else if (mb.BoundMember is Field) {
                    // this occurs for a class level static variable
                    var f = (Field) mb.BoundMember;
                    var loc = (f.IsStatic ? CodeLocation.StaticVariable : CodeLocation.MemberVariable);
                    Add(currentC2, f.Type, loc);
                    Add(currentC2, f.DeclaringType, loc);
                }
                //else if (mb.BoundMember is PropertyNode) { // can this happen?
                //}
                else {
                    alert = true;
                }
            }
            else if (exp is ConstructArray) {
                var ca = (ConstructArray) exp;
                Add(currentC2, ca.ElementType, currentLoc);
            }
            else if (exp is UnaryExpression) {
                // e.g. a method call
                var ue = (UnaryExpression) exp;
                stack.Push(ue.Operand);
            }
            else if (exp is BinaryExpression) {
                var be = (BinaryExpression) exp;
                stack.Push(be.Operand1);
                stack.Push(be.Operand2);
            }
            else if (exp is TernaryExpression) {
                var te = (TernaryExpression) exp;
                stack.Push(te.Operand1);
                stack.Push(te.Operand2);
                stack.Push(te.Operand3);
            }
            else if (exp is NamedArgument) {
                var na = (NamedArgument) exp;
                stack.Push(na.Value);
            }
            else {
                NodeType nt = exp.NodeType;
                bool ignore = (nt == NodeType.Pop || nt == NodeType.Dup);
                alert = !ignore;
            }

            if (alert)
                Write("x x " + currentC2.FullName + " " + currentMember.FullName + "   " + exp.ToString() + "   NodeType:" + exp.NodeType + "   Type:" + exp.Type);
        }
    }

    public override ProblemCollection Check(ModuleNode module) {
        //Write("Check_ModuleNode: " + module.Name);
        return this.Problems;
    }
    public override ProblemCollection Check(Parameter parameter) {
        //Write("Check_Parameter: " + parameter.Name);
        return this.Problems;
    }
    public override ProblemCollection Check(Resource resource) {
        //Write("Check_Resource: " + resource.Name);
        return this.Problems;
    }

    public override ProblemCollection Check(TypeNode type) {
        //Write("Check_TypeNode: " + type.FullName + "  declaring type: " + (type.DeclaringType == null ? "null" : type.DeclaringType.FullName) + " " + type.Interfaces);
        currentC2 = GetClass2(type.FullName, type);

        base.Check(type);

        AttributeNodeCollection attribs = type.Attributes;
        //Write("attributs.COunt: " + attribs.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < attribs.Count; i++) {
            AttributeNode a = attribs[i];
            //Write("a.Type: " + a.Type);
            Add(currentC2, a.Type, CodeLocation.ClassDef);
        }

        InterfaceCollection iList = type.Interfaces;
        for (int i = 0; i < iList.Count; i++) {
            InterfaceNode n = iList[i];
            Add(currentC2, n, CodeLocation.ClassDef);
        }

        return this.Problems;
    }

    private static Class2 GetClass2(String fullName, TypeNode ty) {
        lock(dictTypes) {
            Class2 ct = null;
            if (!dictTypes.TryGetValue(fullName, out ct)) {
                AssemblyNode a = ty.ContainingAssembly();
                bool isEntryPoint = false;
                Method ep = a.EntryPoint;
                if (ep != null)
                    isEntryPoint = (String.Compare(fullName, ep.DeclaringType.FullName) == 0);

                TypeNode dt = ty.DeclaringType;
                TypeNode bt = ty.BaseType;
                
                String dt_ = (dt == null ? "" : dt.FullName);
                String bt_ = (bt == null ? "" : bt.FullName);
                //Write("type: " + ty.FullName + " nt:" + ty.NodeType + " dt:" + dt_ + " bt:" + bt_);
                ct = new Class2(fullName, isEntryPoint, dt_, bt_, ty.NodeType);
                dictTypes[fullName] = ct;
            }
            return ct;
        }
    }


    public override ProblemCollection Check(String namespaceName, TypeNodeCollection types) {
        //Write("Check_namespaceName_types: " + namespaceName + ", " + types.Count);
        return this.Problems;
    }

    protected override String GetLocalizedString(String name, params Object[] arguments) {
        String s = base.GetLocalizedString(name, arguments);
        //Write("GetLocalizedString: " + name);
        return s;
    }
    protected override Resolution GetNamedResolution(String name, params Object[] arguments) {
        Resolution r = base.GetNamedResolution(name, arguments);
        //Write("GetNamedResolution: " + name);
        return r;
    }

    private static void Write(String message, StreamWriter sw = null, bool console = false) {
        if (dictOutput == null) {
            if (console)
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            
            if (sw != null)
                sw.WriteLine(message);

            return;
        }

        lock(dictOutput) {
            int id = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            StringBuilder sb = null;
            if (!dictOutput.TryGetValue(id, out sb)) {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                dictOutput[id] = sb;
            }
            sb.AppendLine(message);
        }
    }

    // chops off "Node" at the end, e.g: EnumNode > Node, DelegateNode > Delegate
    private static String GetName(NodeType nt) {
        String s = nt.ToString();
        if (s.EndsWith("Node"))
            s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 4);
        return s;
    }

    private static void FinalAnalysis() {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, StringBuilder> pair in dictOutput) {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread Id: " + pair.Key);
            Console.Write(pair.Value);
        }
        dictOutput = null;

        bool writeRefs = false;
        bool console = false;
        String outputFilename = null;
        StreamWriter sw2 = null;
        String[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(); // look at the args to determine what to output

        foreach (String arg in args) {
            if (arg.StartsWith("/out:")) {
                outputFilename = arg.Substring(5);
                String folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(outputFilename);
                if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                sw2 = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(outputFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
            }
            else if (arg == "/c" || arg == "/console")
                console = true;
            else if (arg == "/v" || arg == "/verbose")
                writeRefs = true;
        }


        Write("", sw2, console);

        List<Class2> ctList = dictTypes.Values.OrderBy(t => t.FullName).ToList();
        Hashtable htCluster = new Hashtable();
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        foreach (Class2 ct in ctList)
            ht[ct.FullName] = ct;

        foreach (Class2 ct in ctList) {
            if (ct.DeclaringType.Length == 0) {
                List<Class2> list = new List<Class2>();
                list.Add(ct);
                htCluster[ct] = list;
            }
        }

        foreach (Class2 ct in ctList) {
            if (ct.DeclaringType.Length == 0)
                continue;

            var ct2 = ct;
            while (ct2.DeclaringType.Length > 0)
                ct2 = (Class2) ht[ct2.DeclaringType];

            List<Class2> list = (List<Class2>) htCluster[ct2];
            ct2 = ct;
            while (ct2.DeclaringType.Length > 0) {
                list.Add(ct2);
                ct2 = (Class2) ht[ct2.DeclaringType];
            }
            htCluster[ct] = list;
        }

        if (writeRefs) {
            Write("ClassName,RefersTo,Locations", sw2, console);
            foreach (Class2 ct in ctList) {
                List<RefItem> refList = ct.GetRefs();
                foreach (RefItem ri in refList)
                    Write(ct.FullName + "," + ri.FullName + "," + ri.Locations.ToString().Replace(',', ' '), sw2, console);
            }
        }

        // if a nested class points to a parent class, don't count that as a reference
        // if the only reference to class A is the construtor body of class B and class B extends class A, then don't count that as a reference
        int n = ctList.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // check for other classes (ct2) that refer to ct
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (i == j)
                    continue;

                Class2 ct = ctList[i];
                Class2 ct2 = ctList[j];

                bool isNested = false;
                String dt = ct2.DeclaringType;
                while (dt.Length > 0) {
                    var p = (Class2) ht[dt];
                    if (p == ct) {
                        isNested = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    dt = p.DeclaringType;
                }

                if (isNested) {
                    //Write("Skipping: " + ct2.FullName + " because it is a nested class of: " + ct.FullName);
                    continue;
                }

                RefItem ri = ct2.GetRef(ct.FullName);
                if (ri == null)
                    continue; // no references exist
    
                if (ri.Locations == CodeLocation.ConstructorBody) {
                    bool isDescendant = false;
                    // ConstructorBody is the only location typically because of the implicit "base()" call.
                    // Check if ct2 is a descendant class of ct. If so, don't count the reference.          
                    String bt = ct2.BaseType;
                    while (bt.Length > 0) {
                        var p = (Class2) ht[bt];
                        if (p == null)
                            break;

                        if (p == ct) {
                            isDescendant = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        bt = p.BaseType;
                    }

                    if (isDescendant)
                        continue; // skip, does not count as a reference
                }

                var list1 = (List<Class2>) htCluster[ct];
                var list2 = (List<Class2>) htCluster[ct2];
                if (list1 != list2) {
                    // group the nodes as part of the same cluster
                    List<Class2> list3 = new List<Class2>();
                    list3.AddRange(list1);
                    list3.AddRange(list2);
                    foreach (Class2 c2 in list3)
                        htCluster[c2] = list3;

                    //Write("Merged: [" + String.Join(", ", list1.Select(t => t.FullName)) + "] and [" + String.Join(", ", list2.Select(t => t.FullName)) + "]", sw2, console);
                }

                while (ct != null) {
                    if (ct2 != ct)
                        ct.Nbors.Add(ct2);

                    //Console.WriteLine(ct.FullName + ".Nbors.Add(" + ct2.FullName + ")");
                    ct = (Class2) ht[ct.DeclaringType];
                }

            }
        }

        // for each type that has a non-ConstructorBody reference, the ancestor types are counted as references.
        // for example, if there were 5 classes A to E, where each one extends the one before it, i.e: A < B < C < D < E
        // Suppose only class C is referenced somewhere in the code, then classes A & B are considered to be used,
        // but classes D & E are considered unused.
        foreach (Class2 ct in ctList) {
            if (ct.Nbors.Count == 0)
                continue;

            Class2 ct2 = ct;
            String bt = ct2.BaseType;
            while (bt.Length > 0) {
                var p = (Class2) ht[bt];
                if (p == null)
                    break;

                if (p.Nbors.Count == 0)
                    p.Nbors.Add(ct2);

                bt = p.BaseType;
                ct2 = p;
            }
        }

        List<List<Class2>> clusters = htCluster.Values.Cast<List<Class2>>().Distinct().ToList();
        List<List<Class2>> clusters2 = new List<List<Class2>>();
        foreach (List<Class2> list in clusters) {
            if (list.FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsEntryPoint) != null)
                continue; // the cluster that contains the Main() method is not reported as an isolated cluster

            // a cluster must have two or more non-related, non-nested classes
            var list2 = list.Where(t => t.DeclaringType.Length == 0).ToList();
            if (list2.Count > 1)
                clusters2.Add(list2);
        }

        if (clusters2.Count > 0) {
            Write(clusters2.Count + " isolated code clusters detected:", sw2, console);
            for (int i = 0; i < clusters2.Count; i++) {
                List<Class2> list = clusters2[i];
                list.Sort();
                Write("Cluster " + (i+1) + " has " + list.Count + " classes:", sw2, console);
                for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++) {
                    Write("  " + (j+1) + ". " + list[j].FullName + " (" + GetName(list[j].NodeType) + ")", sw2, console);
                }
                Write("", sw2, console);
            }
        }

        // the class that contains the entry point is not reported as unused
        // Don't report anonymous classes (classes that have "<>" in the name)
        List<Class2> ctUnused = ctList.Where(t => t.Nbors.Count == 0 && t.FullName.IndexOf("<>") < 0 && !t.IsEntryPoint).ToList();
        if (ctUnused.Count > 0) {               
            // group by NodeType
            Dictionary<NodeType, List<Class2>> dict = new Dictionary<NodeType, List<Class2>>();
            foreach (Class2 ct in ctUnused) {
                Class2 ct2 = ct;
                bool include = true;
                while (ct2.DeclaringType.Length > 0) {
                    var dt = (Class2) ht[ct2.DeclaringType];
                    if (dt.Nbors.Count == 0) {
                        // don't report a nested class if a parent class will be reported
                        include = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    ct2 = dt;
                }
                if (!include)
                    continue;

                List<Class2> list = null;
                if (!dict.TryGetValue(ct.NodeType, out list)) {
                    list = new List<Class2>();
                    dict[ct.NodeType] = list;
                }
                list.Add(ct);
            }

            List<NodeType> types = dict.Keys.ToList();
            types.Sort();
            foreach (NodeType key in types) {
                String keyName = GetName(key);  
                List<Class2> list = dict[key];
                Write("", sw2, console);
                if (list.Count > 1)
                    Write("The following " + list.Count + " " + keyName + "s are not used by other code:", sw2, console);
                else
                    Write("The following " + keyName + " is not used by other code:", sw2, console);

                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
                    Write((i + 1) + ": " + list[i].FullName, sw2, console);
                }
            }
        }

        if (sw2 != null) {
            sw2.Flush();
            sw2.Dispose();
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding of the question , you are opting to find classes that cannot be reached from main method that is in the batch.

As per the layout of the solution, all the classes can be reached from the main method project by adding references and by making use of the **using** keyword.External references to other solution projects can be done by adding dll and then importing the namespace.

And if you want to perform clean up and remove unused classed from your solutions, you need to carefully check direct and indirect references of the classes.

Think the above answers your question, please mark as answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score -4):

Try reading the `.sln` file. It will contain references to all the projects used. 
For each project used, open the `.csproj` file. All files under `compile` are used for project building. You can safely remove other files assuming you have one class per file.

Comment: You may have misunderstood the question.  The OP isn't asking to find files which aren't referenced by the project.  They're asking to find **classes** which *are* in the project but aren't used by anything.